# Piping the contents of a file into AWK

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Using the following AWK program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=":" }

NR==1 { next; }
/^[1]/ { print $0; count++; }

END { printf("%d lines identified. File processing complete", count) }
```

I am attempting to pass data to the script in the following manner:

cat bio.data | bio.awk

Unfortunately, the shell responds with "bio.awk: command not found"

I used chmod +x on the bio.awk file prior to issuing the command.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `./bio.awk`

Comment: Or `cat bio.data | awk -f bio.awk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example of using GNU `AWK` program from file, let `counter.awk` be

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
END{print "Processed",NR,"lines"}
```

and `numbers.csv` be

```
1,one
2,two
3,three
```

then

```
awk --file counter.awk numbers.csv
```

output

```
Processed 3 lines
```

Explanation: `--file counter.awk` inform GNU `AWK` to use what is inside `counter.awk` rather than first nonoption argument as source. If you want to know more about `--file` read [Command-Line Options in GNU AWK documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html). Note that this solution does not require `x` permission on `counter.awk`

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*